# Chrome Extension Connect To Amazon MWS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, amazon-mws

Whats the best way to connect a chrome extension to the Amazon MWS API's?

Should I store the credentials inside the javascript files?

How would I encrypt the credentials?

Thanks

Comment: There's no point in hiding the API credentials. Any data used in your extension can be viewed in devtools debugger, for example by setting a breakpoint or viewing the network requests of the corresponding script.

Comment: So then most chrome extensions that connect to amazon api's show the credentials?  Whats the best way to handle this?  Should I do my own API and pass through all data to my API?

Comment: Yes, it is the only solution to prevent the API keys from being leaked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this a few times with various clients, whether they be web apps, or windows, or IOS clients.  Doesn't matter, you create an API that your front ends will call and your API handles all the communication with MWS, hiding your access and secret keys from the client.

I used to use a chrome plugin that talked to MWS to get pricing info.  I wanted to figure out how they did it, so I looked at all their javascript and figured it out, including their keys.  They quickly released a new version that called back to their servers, essentially following the method I describe above.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.  Have you written an app to calculate the total number of a specific product that has sold on amazon?  How do these apps estimate the monthly sales of a book for example?  Thanks